# Can VBA API be performed in .net?

Tags: vba

We are trying to improve the administrative UI to an application we have that uses Excel as a portal to a proprietary DB.  All the APIs are written in VBA thus every thing is done in Excel.  Rewriting the APIs does not appear to be an option at this time.

Is there anything we an do to use those APIs in the .net environment?

Comment: VBA is most likely COM based. Probably the scripting flavour (encredible how fast I forget these things). That should be accessible from .net. (VB should be the first choice, more capable for runtime binding than C#)

Comment: I looked and there are ActiveX COM objects exposed

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your API is set up, it might be possible.  See this MSDN article on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159913%28office.11%29.aspx